# $X$ be a geometric random variable, show that $P[X \geq n] = (1-p)^{n-1}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, random

**Question:** $X$ be a geometric random variable, show that $P[X \geq n] = (1-p)^{n-1}$

---

**Attempted Solution:**

Let $X$ be a geometric random variable, that is, $X$ counts the number of independent Bernoulli trials until the first success occurs.

We wish to find, given some number $n \in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, $P[X \geq n]$, that is, the probability that $n$ or more attempts are required before the first success occurs.

Suppose that attempt results in success with probability $p$. Let $$[][][][][][][][][]....[]$$ denote a set of attempts. We know that $n-1$ attempts all result in failure, then the probability of those attempts are $1-p$. So the probability of having $n-1$ failures is $(1-p)^{n-1}$.

---

**Difficulty:**

I am having trouble seeing that the event "having $n-1$ failures" equivalent to "need $n$ or more attempts"

Secondly, I know that for a geometric random variable, the PMF is $P[X = n] = (1-p)^{n-1}p$. Where does the $p$ go in this case?

Is there an alternative, ***axiomatic*** derivation of $P[X \geq n]$?

e.g. $P[X \geq n] = 1 - P[X < n]$ Don't know $P[X < n]$...

Much thanks!

Comment: If we need at least $n$ to have a success, this means that the first success must occur from $n$ onwards. This means that the previous $n-1$ attempts must not have a success in it, otherwise the first success would have occurred before the $n$th attempt. The first $n-1$ attempts not having a success is then the same thing as all $n-1$ attempts not being successful, i.e they are all failures

Comment: Regards to your second point, once we realize that we are looking for the probability that the first $n-1$ attempts are fails, we are not dealing with a geometric distribution anymore, but rather a binomial distribution. If we let $Y$ have distribution $Bin(n-1, p-1)$, we see that the probability of first $n-1$ fails is the same as $P(Y=n-1)$

Comment: To answer the question you may start from $P(X=x)=(1-p)^{x-1}p$ and use the summation for geometric series to establish the result.

Comment: @Math-fun Elegant! I like it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P[X \geq x] = \sum\limits_{x = n}^\infty P[X = x] = \sum\limits_{x = n}^\infty (1-p)^{x-1}p = \dfrac{p}{1-p} \sum\limits_{x = n}^\infty (1-p)^x =  \dfrac{p}{1-p} \dfrac{(1-p)^n}{p}$$

Establishes the result.

Comment: your indexes got muddled a little, you should swap $x$ and $n$.